# RoR app: Problems deploying app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I created an heroku app recently for an existing rails app I've been working on. I only have one html file that I'd like to see displayed on my browser. This file gets news stories from my database (sqlite3-- should technically work from a development standpoint. I've gotten it to work with the railstutorial, where I didn't configure postgres at all), along with their corresponding images, and spits them to the page. This works perfectly on localhost, but when I deploy using 'heroku open', all I see is a blank white page with the heading tag that I added at the very top of the page: 'Top stories from BBC'. It's as if the app doesn't read the eRB tags at all. Here's the code for my index view html.erb file:

```
<h1> Top stories from BBC <h1>


<% @stories.each do |story| %>

<% if story.image.nil? %>

<% # do nothing %>

<% else %>
<div> 
    <h3><%= story.name %></h3>
    <p><%= story.summary %></p>
    <a href = "<%= story.url %>" >
        <img src="<%= story.image %>" />
    </a>
</div>

<% end %>

<% end %>
```

Here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.8'

gem 'feedjira'

gem 'mechanize'

gem 'nokogiri'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
    gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

I keep using heroku and git commands such as :

- git push
- git push heroku
- heroku run rake db:migrate
- rake assets:precompile
- git add . /git commit -m/etc.
- git push heroku master

Even after trying the above in multiple different combinations, nothing seems to work. I would appreciate any feedback you guys can offer as to how I can get my index page to render properly over Heroku. It works perfectly over local host.

Thanks, your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think problem is with database, either your database is not configured on heroku or your stories are empty on heroku database

Comment: Can you show us your controller?

Comment: In the config/environments/production.rb file, did you change to this **config.serve_static_assets = true**   ?

Answer (score 1):

You've pushed your code to Heroku, but your Heroku database is empty.  If you have data in your local database you want on Heroku just push!

```
 heroku pg:push mylocaldb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA --app sushi
```

Where:

`mylocaldb` is the name of your local databases

`HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA` is the name of your heroku database (find it from `heroku pg:info -a myapp`)

**IMPORTANT**: Heroku uses postgres, so you should be using postgres locally as well.  Many of the commands stated here require you to have postgres installed on your machine.

Be sure to read through the very useful help pages Heroku has: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull

Comment: Thanks but might I ask how I find out the name of mylocaldb? I have now installed postgreSQL and was using sqlite3 before. Much appreciated.

Comment: Check your database.yml file.  Also if your migrating from sqlite to postgres I used the RailsCast and taps: http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql?view=asciicast